Check if id exists and act accordingly in a trigger function
In a trigger function, I want to select an id from a table. If this id exists, I want to do something with it, if not, I want to do something else.
My (not working) code:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.handle_new_user()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    SECURITY DEFINER
AS
$function$
DECLARE
    _organisation_id INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT id FROM public.organisation WHERE $CONDITION
    RETURNING id
        INTO _organisation_id;

    // check if _organisation_id is set
    RETURN new;
END;
$function$

Can I store the id in to _organisation_id like that? What happens if there is no id? Is it correct to declare it as INT? Or do I need to declare it explicitly that it can be INT or Null or something?
How do I check if the id is set? How do I do this if/else structure in PL/pgSQL?
The trigger function is called when a new user signs up to my supabase project. This is the trigger:
-- trigger the function every time a user is created
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();

My organisation.id is a bigint.

From the (too) many questions you are asking I get the idea that you are pretty new to PostgreSQL ann SQL. Perhaps you should spend some time with the documentation, so that you understand the principles behind data types and triggers.

@LaurenzAlbe Yeah, like most of the questions can be combined to the question on how to store the result of the select. The only other question is the if/else. But I can figure that out myself. Yes I am very new to it.

It depends on the data type of the table column. But why is that a trigger function? How is the trigger defined? What is its purpose? You see, it is not possible to write a meaningful answer. without more information. Please don't put that information in comments, [edit] the question.


You need to read  through plpgsql trigger functions several times. Then work you way through plpgsql in particular, Result status. 2) _organisation_id INT and My organisation.id is a bigint is an accident waiting to happen.


@AdrianKlaver thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

You want something like:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.handle_new_user()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS   -- why SECURITY DEFINER ?
$func$
DECLARE
   _org_id bigint;  -- matching type!
BEGIN
   SELECT o.id
   FROM   public.organisation o
   WHERE  -- $CONDITION  -- condition matters!
   INTO   _org_id;

   IF FOUND THEN
      -- do something
   ELSE
      -- do something else
   END IF;

   RETURN NULL;  -- irrelevant for AFTER trigger
END
$func$;

SELECT INTO sets the special variable FOUND.
If you don't actually use _org_idin the function, you can simplify with EXISTS:

PostgreSQL IF statement

Depending on what else you do in the function, there may be a lurking race condition. See:

Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?

On a related note, beware of deadlocks. See:

Deadlock in AFTER INSERT trigger

Or maybe you do not need a trigger at all?

Insert inserted id to another table
For every inserted row, generate series of rows in another table with AFTER INSERT trigger

And read up basics on trigger functions in the manual, as has been suggested in comments.
